# Accessing function from exported module (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been reading up on this and apprently there are more ways to export a module in node.js.

One of the simple things you can do with modules is to encapsulate functions within a file like so:

```
module.exports = {
  sayHelloInEnglish: function() {
    return "HELLO";
  },

  sayHelloInSpanish: function() {
    return "Hola";
  }
};
```

However i would like to create some more dirverse modules and so ive created the following user module:

```
    var UserModule = function (socket) {
    var userList = [];

    socket.on('userData', function (userDetails) {
        userDetails.socket = socket;
        userList[userDetails.id] = userDetails
    });

    socket.on('getActiveUsers', function () {
        socket.emit('activeUsers', userList);
    });

    function helloWorld (){
        console.log('hello world');
    }

};

module.exports = function (socket) {
    return new UserModule(socket);
};
```

now i am requireing this module in my io instance:

```
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var my_user = userList.id;
    socket.on('userData', function (userDetails) {
        userDetails.socket = socket;
        userList[userDetails.id] = userDetails
    });


    var userModule = require('./costum_modules/UserModule.js')(socket);
    userModule.helloWorld();
    var chatModule = require('./costum_modules/ChatModule.js')(socket, userModule);
    var cacheModule = require('./costum_modules/CacheModule.js')(socket, userModule);
    var notificationModule = require('./costum_modules/NotificationModule')(socket, sequelize, userList);

});
```

The `socket.on` methods are working fine in my `UserModule` however i am unable to call the function `helloWorld`. if i try i get the following error:

```
userModule.helloWorld is not a function
```

So my question is, is what i am trying to do even possible? how am i able to store `objects`, `functions` ect in a module for later use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function helloWorld` is essentially a private function for use within your userModule.

You can make it public by changing the function declaration to the following:

```
this.helloWorld = function (){
    console.log('hello world');
}
```